# Comparison of two AR(1) regression models (lead in dependent vs lag in dependent variable)

Tags: regression, time-series

What is the difference between these time series AR(1) regression models (lead in the dependent vs lag in the dependent variable)?

$$\begin{align}y_t = constant + \alpha y_{t-1} + error \tag{1}\label{eq1}\\
y_{t+1} = constant + \alpha y_{t} + error \tag{2}\label{eq2}\end{align}$$

Will they have different coefficients?

Comment: Consider posting questions like this on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions) instead. There is a higher concentration of questions of this type and probably more experts to answer them.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. Coefficients for both AR models will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no difference between these two models. You've just indexed the variable $y$ in a different style.